# I need to add alert when main plot change color green to red and red to green

Tags: tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I hope I can get this workingI'm trying to add alert to trigger when main plot change color green to red and red to green

Here's the original script
FULL CODE
https://www.tradingview.com/script/B3hl90F2-FATL-SATL-RFTL-RSTL-Digital-Signal-Filter-Smoother-Loxx/

THANKS FOR YOUR HELP

I added this addition but it won't comply and the indicator won't work

buy = avg > avg[1] ? greencolor
sell =avg > avg[1] ? redcolor

plotshape(buy), style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(#046ff9, 0), size=size.large, text='PineConnector \n B', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))

plotshape(sell), style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(#046ff9, 0), size=size.large, text='PineConnector \n S', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))